# Getting only selected fields of user timeline from Twitter API

Tags: twitter

I am getting user's timeline from an iOS app, with a big number of tweets being pulled from the API. I am using the `statuses/user_timeline` endpoint to get the data, however, as I'm on a mobile device and as I only need the tweet text only, I'd like to filter only the actual text data of the tweets. I've already set `include_entities` to `no` and `trim_user` to `true`, but even with entities and user data trimmed off, I'm still getting a lot of data that I don't need. Here is a sample tweet that I get from the endpoint:

```
{
"created_at": "Tue Nov 27 14:13:13 +0000 2012",
"id": 273429272209801200,
"id_str": "273429272209801217",
"text": "you could list #5ThingsIFindAttractive but you can actually find them on Facebook with Social Match on iPhone! http://t.co/zRr1ggbz",
"source": "web",
"truncated": false,
"in_reply_to_status_id": null,
"in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
"in_reply_to_user_id": null,
"in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
"in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
"user": {
  "id": 62828168,
  "id_str": "62828168"
},
"geo": null,
"coordinates": null,
"place": {
  "id": "682c5a667856ef42",
  "url": "http://api.twitter.com/1/geo/id/682c5a667856ef42.json",
  "place_type": "country",
  "name": "Turkey",
  "full_name": "Turkey",
  "country_code": "TR",
  "country": "Turkey",
  "bounding_box": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          25.663883,
          35.817497
        ],
        [
          44.822762,
          35.817497
        ],
        [
          44.822762,
          42.109993
        ],
        [
          25.663883,
          42.109993
        ]
      ]
    ]
  },
  "attributes": {}
},
"contributors": null,
"retweet_count": 0,
"favorited": false,
"retweeted": false,
"possibly_sensitive": false
```

}

The only thing I actually need is the `text` key of the dictionary. The rest is currently useless for my app. I'll be requesting LOTS of tweets like this. How can I send a request to just to pull of the `text` key of the tweets? Currently, this method is *extremely* inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  The best you can do is set up a proxy which will request the data, strip it back, and then forward it to the mobile.

If it's any consolation, the JSON will be gzip'd and so should still be relatively small - so won't take too long to transfer or eat in to the user's data allowance.

Comment: ok, I'll be gzipping the data, which would be the best for my case.. sad to see there is no equivalent of the graph/fql api of facebook where we select the fields we only need.